# Using ArcPy to Intersect Line and Polygon Features of the Same Name

Tags: arcpy, intersect, code-review

I have a file geodatabase containing line and polygon feature classes of the same name. Below is an example:

- NATGAS_6IN_Line
- NATGAS_6IN_Polygon
- CAD_ARD_6IN_Line
- CAD_ARD_6IN_Polygon

I have 20 line and polygons pairs I want to intersect. The line must only be intersected with the polygon of the matching name, e.g., the NATGAS_6IN line must only be intersected with the NATGAS_6IN polygon. Because I have 20 sets, I want to write a loop that iterates through the geodatabase so I don't have to write 20 individual arcpy.analysis.Intersect lines of code. The for loop I've come up with looks like this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = buffer_cl_gdb
for file in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='ALL'):
    Line_List = ['NATGAS_6IN','CAD_ARD_8IN']
    for name in Line_List:
        buffer =  '{}_buffers'.format(name)
        centerline = '{}_CL'.format(name)
        output = class_segments_gdb +"\\" + os.path.basename(name)
        print(buffer)
        arcpy.analysis.Intersect([buffer,centerline],output)
```

This code does work, however, it iterates through the Line_List 40 times for some reason. I would like it to only iterate through the list once.

Any thoughts on how to improve the code?

Comment: For code review there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you have a redundant loop that is causing it to loop over all datasets.  The offending line, which you don't actually use in any way, is:

```py
for file in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='ALL'):
```

Your code should be:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = buffer_cl_gdb
Line_List = ['NATGAS_6IN','CAD_ARD_8IN']
for name in Line_List:
    buffer =  '{}_buffers'.format(name)
    centerline = '{}_CL'.format(name)
    output = class_segments_gdb +"\\" + os.path.basename(name)
    print(buffer)
    arcpy.analysis.Intersect([buffer,centerline],output)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much!